# Select Option Of Radio Button From a Different Process

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, pinvoke

i tried to click on radio button of other process:

[image]

this is my code:

```
    Dim hh As IntPtr = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess")(0).MainWindowHandle
    Dim TheSelectionBox As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hh, 0, "Options:", "Button")
    ClickOnOption(TheSelectionBox, 2)
```

i have the "Options" box handle, 
now i want to click on `radio button` in the "Options" box.
how can i click on the radio button?

Comment: try to to revise your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two radio buttons are in fact `BUTTON` controls. They are children of the containing group window. So you need to enumerate those children, by calling [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) to find the appropriate button. Then you can send that button the [`BM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) message to simulation pressing it.

By the way, `FindWindowEx(hh, 0, "Options:", "Button")` won't find your window. You are asking it to match a window with class name `Options:` and title `Button`. I'm confident that call to `FindWindowEx` will return zero. Personally I'd call `EnumChildWindows` on the top level window and stop when you find a window with title `"Option 2"`. And so avoid having to use `FindWindowEx` at all.